# Windows Mobile 6 tapi and OpenNetCF telephone

Tags: compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5, pocketpc, tapi, opennetcf

I have a Ciperlab scanner running Windows Mobile 6 and compact framework 3.5. I have developed a phone interface from the app using OpenNetCF Telephony. This works well but at times the "hangup" takes up to 80 seconds before the "disconnected" event is driven". The OpenNetCF "hangup" method is a simple wrapper for the native tapi "lineDrop" method. Calling "lineDrop" without using the OpenNetCF wrapper gives the same problem. To try to break out of the 80 second delay I have a timer. In the timer_tick event I have tried to dispose of and re-initialise OpenNetCF but this then hangs the entire program and I have to reboot. Any suggestions on what is causing this 80 second delay and how to avoid it / break out of it would be welcomed

Comment: How long does it take when you manually call and disconnect? I assume this lineDrop call is overloaded. Possibly using TAPI like http://programmaremobile.blogspot.de/2009/10/how-to-make-call-with-opennetcf-tapi.html is faster.

Comment: I have disabled the manual interface so don't know. The hung is intermittent. More tests indicate that it could to be caused by the lineDrop  being called from a timer expired event. The LineDrop is called from the OpenNetCF "HangUp" method which I call. I have tried calling the LineDrop directly but the results are the same.

Comment: I have restored the standard MS phone support and this works fine. More tests lead me to believe that OpenNetCF is not immediately forwarding all the TAPI events to my program hence the reason for the "hang" - actually it is not a hang but a very long delay. I also note that when using OpenNetCF the phone icons on the top line are not being updated. I have OpenNetCF V1. Is there a later version avl;? How do I go about finding why events are being delayed?